# Use of Java code in other platforms using Mono

Tags: c#, java, binding, mono, cross-platform

I am working on a project which is written in Java (6.0) and I want to use it in almost all the platforms (iOS/Android/Windows/Windows Phone/Mac/Linux) so I thought of Mono and converting the code to C# but it's 40,000 line of code so it would take so much time to write that. Then I realized that I can use JavaBinding to convert a lot of it and use it but I am not sure if I can use it in Windows or more important iOS.

So basically my question is that "Does java binding converts Java code to C# or it's just a call to the java code? If so, I can't use it for my MonoTouch project"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches are possible,

1. Use Sharpen to convert Java code to C# code. A perfect example, is to port Android to C# http://blog.xamarin.com/android-in-c-sharp/
2. Use IKVM to host Java code on Mono. http://www.ikvm.net/

JavaBinding is only useful for Mono for Android, and I don't think it applies to Windows/iOS.

Comment: Totally true, I can't use JavaBinding anywhere but MonoTouch! I am trying Sharpen for now.